# How can I write and read a text doucument in a folder?

Tags: c#

```
string curetn = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string path = curetn.ToString() + @"\DATA\SaveGame.txt";
Console.WriteLine(path);
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path);
```

Hello, I am making a text-adventure, and I do not like having all my save files, and mp3 file in the same place as my application. I would like for the files to be in a folder. I want to be able to use StreamWriter and StreamReader, to be able to write and read files that are in a folder. This file is also in a distributable folder, not just in the Visual Studios Projects folders. I have tried everything I can, and this is what I have. I also have one of these for StreamWriter. Please help!

Edit:
The thing that does not work, is that it does not read the lines, and assigns them to a variable. I have it in a try-catch, and it catches, and displays the error message that I wrote.

Comment: What isn't working? You seem to have the right idea...

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for StreamWriter / StreamReader? There are some simple examples here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter and here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Comment: your first two lines equal to `path = @"DATA\SaveGame.txt"`. what doesn't work? What do you expect?  What is your question? BTW: You can't use StreamRader/Writer for binary files like *mp3*.

Comment: You may also want to check out `File.ReadAllText` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `File.WriteAllText` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't see any error message in your post...

Comment: [C# Examples Look at FileOpen Methods](http://www.csharp-examples.net/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for simply read and write lines from file you can try this

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        sr.ReadLine();
     }            
}

string s;
using (StreamWriter sw  = new StreamWriter(path))
{              
     sw.WriteLine(s);

}
```

Comment: If you need to read the entire file just use File.ReadAllText, don't bother with StreamReader

Comment: Or `File.ReadLines` `File.WriteAllLines`, if you need it to read/write line by line.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to do is read the text file:

```
string data[] = File.ReadAllLines(path); // Read the text file.
var x = data[1]; // Replace the '1' with the line number you want.
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This is a good way to read the text file, I think it's better than opening a stream.

You can also write to it, so every time you want to save, just do this:

```
// When you want to write:
File.WriteAllText(path, "");
File.AppendAllText(path, "Add a data line" + Environment.NewLine); // Environment.NewLine adds a line.
```

Keep appending text to the file for the data you need.

Comment: `I think it's better than opening a stream.` What do you think `File.ReadAllLines` does? BTW: It reads all lines to memory at once, the lazy version `File.ReadLines` may be better.

Comment: @L.B I know, reading all lines is fast and it saves you a crap ton of code.

Comment: `AppendAllText` doesn't add a line, simple a text. (No newline char by default)

Comment: Oh. Adding something now! @L.B

Comment: @L.B done. I added an `Environment.NewLine` into it.